VS Code showing loading ARMschema all the time
When I want to create an ARM template for Azure in VS Code I installed Azure Resource Manager Tools extension. But when I create an ARM template in VS Code it's showing "loading ARM schemas" all the time and it is not completing. When I  hover on any of the contentversion, parameters, variable  it's showing "loading". I tried restarting and uninstalling and reinstalling the extension. I even tried with reinstalling VS Code as well.
I tried checking the internet connection; it's all good. I tried to disable and restarting the ARM tool extension. I reinstalled VS Code several times; still the issue persists.

Have you tried any particular code? @vishnu k
